# Asp.Net Core [FromRoute] auto url decode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, urlencode

If we have such controller endpoint in Asp.Net Core:

```
[HttpGet("/api/resources/{someParam}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> TestEndpoint([FromRoute] string someParam)
{
    string someParamUrlDecoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(someParam);
    // do stuff with url decoded param...
}
```

Is there some way to configure `[FromRoute]` parsing behavior in such way that it will inject into `someParam` already url decoded value?

Comment: Can you share examples?

Comment: My particular usecase almost the same as attached in first message. I just changed variable names. In fact, I just want to receive here `([FromRoute] string someParam)` value, which already has been url decoded. And remove `string someParamUrlDecoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(someParam);` operations from controller methods. So I think there should be some point, where it is possible to intercept value, which will be injected as value of parameter annotated with `[FromRoute]` attribute and change it. But I haven't found the way.

Comment: Can you share example _values_ for `someParam`?

Comment: I have such value for `someParam`: `384865_38A/X` before url encoding. So without encoding this leads to 404 response code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to achieve whatever you're trying to do is to create a custom Attribute. Within the attribute you can essentially intercept the incoming parameter and perform whatever you need.

Attribute Definition:

```
public class DecodeQueryParamAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        string param = context.ActionArguments["param"] as string;
        context.ActionArguments["param"] = "Blah"; // this is where your logic is going to sit
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

And within the controller, you'll need to decorate the action method with the attribute as done below. Route can be modified according to your need.

```
[HttpGet("/{param}")]
[Attributes.DecodeQueryParamAttribute]
public void Process([FromRoute] string param)
{
    // value of param here is 'Blah'
    // Action method
}
```

As a word of caution, when you are going to have encoded strings being passed as query string parameters, you may want to check about allowing [Double Escaping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/settings-schema/ms689460(v=vs.90)#attributes) and its implications.

Comment: this seems to be working in my local, but when i deploy in any windows server then it's not working. any possible reason you can think of?